# How can I call an stored procedure on CosmosDb with custom serialization with .net Sdk version 3?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

What I want to do is to call a SP with a specific Json serialization configuration using cosmos .net Sdk version 3.

With version 2 I could do it setting the RequestOptions JsonSerializerSettings property in the call.

Now with version 3 I don't have that option, the only one I have is to set the custom configuration at the client object level.

Is this the only option available?
I have to create a new client for each configuration I need?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `ExecuteStoredProcedureStreamAsync`. Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/Scripts/Scripts.cs#L434

It's signature is:

```
public abstract Task<ResponseMessage> ExecuteStoredProcedureStreamAsync(
    string storedProcedureId,
    PartitionKey partitionKey,
    dynamic[] parameters,
    StoredProcedureRequestOptions requestOptions = null,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

That means that it will give you a `ResponseMessage` back, with a `Content` (Stream) you can deserialize however you want.

If what you want to serialize the Input, there is another method:

```
 public abstract Task<ResponseMessage> ExecuteStoredProcedureStreamAsync(
            string storedProcedureId,
            Stream streamPayload,
            PartitionKey partitionKey,
            StoredProcedureRequestOptions requestOptions = null,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

Where the `streamPayload` is a `Stream`. Sample usage: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/fad3daf789458bc73256d4b26bdd1e4cfc83b2ad/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/tests/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.EmulatorTests/StoredProcedureTests.cs#L474

```
MemoryStream streamPayload = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"[""one"",""two"",""three""]"));

ResponseMessage response = await this.scripts.ExecuteStoredProcedureStreamAsync(
    storedProcedureId: sprocId,
    streamPayload: streamPayload,
    partitionKey: new Cosmos.PartitionKey(testPartitionId),
    requestOptions: null,
    cancellationToken: default(CancellationToken));
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Matias. But what I need to do is to serialize with different options the object I set in the SP parameters. Not the response.

Comment: Added in the answer

Comment: Thanks Matias! Exactly what I needed.